# How Can I Execute *.exe From Table Trigger?

Tags: sql, database

i would like to start an exe or dll once record is updated. If field of interest is updated i would like to call an *.exe with parameters. Is this possible in MySql and oracle?

Comment: A good question is "why?"  A lot of modern databases have built-in functionality to send email, call web services, etc... In Oracle, these are done through various packages like `UTL_MAIL` and `UTL_SMTP`.

Comment: Do you want the executable called synchronously or asynchronously? And do you want the call to the exe to transactional? For instance, if a record is updated, the trigger fires, and then the update rolls back, what about the work that the exe did? Also, be warned Oracle has restarts, and can call a trigger multiple times per update.

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue came up recently in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683243/best-way-to-call-a-web-service-from-tsql/2683363#2683363). While that poster was trying to make a web call within a trigger, the same general response ("this is not a good idea") is probably true here as well.